# Expected Identifier or '(' when compiling Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

So I am trying to make this camera app but every time I try an run it, it says " Expected Identifier or '('. I get two of these error's. One of them right under 
`- (IBAction)takePhoto:(UIButton *)sender;` and one under `- (IBAction)selectPhoto:(UIButton *)sender;`
Thanks

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface APPViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *ImageView;


- (IBAction)takePhoto:(UIButton *)sender;
{
 UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType =UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (IBAction)selectPhoto:(UIButton *)sender;
{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
@end
```

Comment: I think you need to step back and find a good basic Objective-C tutorial. You need to learn what goes in a .h file and what goes in the .m file.

Comment: What on this good earth are you doing? Why is your implementation in what I can only assume is your `.h` file? Have you done any tutorials at all?

Comment: Basically you've got two declarations, and directly under them sets of statements enclosed in `{}` and not attached to anything.  The declarations ended with the `;` characters.  And, as others have indicated, unless you really know what you're doing the declarations should stay in the .h and the method bodies in the .m (with suitable method headers -- essentially the declarations sans `;` -- preceding the bodies, and with the appropriate @implementation/@end statements surrounding the whole mess).

Answer (score 5):

The `@interface` (generally the .h file) holds only the class interface. It shouldn't contain the class implementation (the method contents). That goes in the .m file (specifically, the `@ implementation`). So you need to move it there.

Comment: The `.h` and `.m` can both have an `@interface`.  This issue isn't `.h` versus `.m` so much as it is `@interface` versus `@implementation`.

Comment: @nhgrif yes you are right. But as per code its .h file. Wain is correct.

Comment: @nhgrif In this case the `@interface` is not a class extension.

Comment: @Reformer My comment was mostly to point out that the questioner needed to do more than simply copy & paste over from `.h` to `.m`.  He'd see the same errors if this code were in the `@interface` of the `.m` file.  It has to be in the `@implementation`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to call your methods from outside your class you have to place their signatures in the .h file, like so :

```
@interface APPViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>

- (IBAction)takePhoto:(UIButton *)sender;
- (IBAction)selectPhoto:(UIButton *)sender;

@end
```

and then in your .m file you should have something like this (I am leaving the property in the private interface so you see how it should look like)

```
@interface APPViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *ImageView;

@end

- (IBAction)takePhoto:(UIButton *)sender
{
 UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType =UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (IBAction)selectPhoto:(UIButton *)sender
{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
@end
```

The things that you should notice in the .m file:

- there are no semicolons after the names of the methods
- the declaration of a private interface (you forgot the `@end` and used the .h file `@interface` declaration)

  - also when you are using properties never use camel case because you will get confused; use lower camel case :

> @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *ImageView;

should be

> @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

Do not forget to use XCode autocompletion to help you out and be more productive.

Comment: Why would you declare an outlet property in a class extension? There's no point to a private outlet.

Comment: [Some among us seem to believe outlets and actions should be private](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17852287/should-i-put-ibactions-in-the-header-file-or-not/17852479#comment30170732_17852479), @rmaddy. They are of course wrong wrong wrong. :)

Comment: Well my reasoning is that XCode does not give me autocompletion for the properties if I'm referencing the view controller from somewhere else. I didn't inspect his code carefully, but myself, as a general rule I do not put properties in the .h files unless I need reference those in other places.