# Storyboard custom class is ignored

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode-storyboard

[image: Custom class input]

I'm attempting to add a custom view controller to my storyboard. The view controller `KTResearchUploadViewController` appears in the "Custom Class" class dropdown, and I have selected it. Inside the view controller (on the storyboard), I have a button that is linked to `KTResearchUploadViewController` to call a method `handleUploadButtonPress` on primary action.

When the button is pressed, I receive this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController handleUploadButtonPress:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x11c33b740'
```

It looks like it's trying to call `handleUploadButtonPress` on `UIViewController` rather than `KTResearchUploadViewController`. What am I doing wrong here?

`KTResearchUploadViewController.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface KTResearchUploadViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

`KTResearchUploadViewController.m`

```
#import "KTResearchUploadViewController.h"

@interface KTResearchUploadViewController ()

@end

@implementation KTResearchUploadViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (IBAction)handleUploadButtonPress:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Button pressed!");
}

@end
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17852287/should-i-put-ibactions-in-the-header-file-or-not

Try adding the ibaction to your .h

Answer (score 1):

Add the IBAction to your .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface KTResearchUploadViewController : UIViewController
- (IBAction)handleUploadButtonPress:(id)sender;
@end
```

Also make sure there is a connection from your button in IB to your code

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ConnectTheUIToCode.html

Comment: I tried both of these, and now I'm receiving this error: `'[<UIViewController 0x11c438f20> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key uploadButton.'`

Comment: where is the key uploadButton from?

Comment: `uploadButton` is the name I gave the connection between the button in the storyboard and `KTResearchUploadViewController`

Comment: Try changing that to handleUploadButtonPress - I can test it out in about 10 if its not working still

Comment: I have `handleUploadButtonPress` defined in both the .m and .h files. `uploadButton` is just a reference to the `UIButton` (I'm not actually using this though).

Comment: I just did it up real quick and it worked fine - but the name of the connection should be the name of the action. http://imgur.com/a/iZxHO

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152795/discussion-between-solenoid-and-simplej).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the cause of the original problem but I've just had a similar problem and ended up here. Eventually I figured out that my `ViewController` sub-class was not a member of the target that I was running in Xcode. For some reason in this case it just defaults to using `ViewController` instead.